# PHP - proper check if $_POST['variable'] is posted

Tags: php, post, isset

I want to check if $_POST['submit'] is posted.

My original code was:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) { }
```

But I have a PHP notice with this code - "Undefined index: submit in..."

So to remove the notice I have to write this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { }
```

But this is pointless because $_POST array is global and it return always true.
Also if I want to check if $_POST['submit'] is not 0 without PHP notice I have to write this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] != 0) { }
```

In this particular case I prefer:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {}
```

But here I get the PHP notice.

So which way is the most proper/accepted?

Thank you

Comment: `$_POST` is not true unless there was a post request. Therefore `isset($_POST['submit']` is definitely not always set. `if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] != 0) { }` is not the same as `if ($_POST['submit']) {}`. Check deceze's answer.

Comment: @Viridis Actually, `$_POST` *is* always set: http://3v4l.org/Fm37H

Comment: always exists, not always true: http://3v4l.org/VhOtg

Answer (score 3):

`isset($_POST['submit'])` checks if the `submit` key is set in the `$_POST` array. It doesn't just check whether the `$_POST` array exists and is therefore not "pointless". If you want to check whether the value is *not falsey* (`== false`), which includes `0`, without triggering an error, that's what `empty` is for:

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit']))
```

which is the same thing as

```
if ($_POST['submit'])
```

but without triggering a notice should the value not exist.

See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/) for an exhaustive explanation.

Comment: That's what i was wondering. I think the question was meant like 'how do i check if a post was submitted' rather than 'how do i isset() + not false'.

Comment: Well, that's two different topic. Do I want to find out whether a request is a POST request or do I want to figure out if a specific value was posted? For the record, I like @timus' answer just fine. But I don't understand why mine is supposedly worth downvoting.

Comment: tbh ... is his answer really correct? Timus' checks just whether there was a post request, not if `$_POST['submit'] != 0`. I still believe your answer is more correct :S

Comment: He's avoiding the topic entirely and tries to infer what the OP is really trying to do (check if something was POSTed). I assume `submit` is the name of the submit button form element, and checking for its presence is actually a pretty ugly way to relay "something was posted" to the server. timus' way is more direct, but may or may not be what's needed here.

Comment: "It doesn't just check whether the $_POST array exists and is therefore not "pointless"" - that's right it's my fault. Thank you for the respond. I will stick with the if(isset($_POST['name'])) {}.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
  //do 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I will try this and thank you. Also I want to know if this way is the proper/accepted - I want to stick with the standards when writing code.

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP version 7 there is a new method available called "Null Coalesce Operator". This method saves you time and space in your code.

`$submit = $_POST['submit'] ?? '';`

If submit key does not exist or is NULL the value of the `$submit` variable will be an empty string.

This method is not limited to $_POST. It will work for any variable. For example:

`echo $my_message ?? 'No message found';`

If message was not initialized or is NULL, the statement above will output `No message found`

There's even more that you can do with a null coalesce operator, documentation link below.

[Documentation here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary)

Answer (score 1):

$_POST[] checks to see if a variable is submitted and not the form name.

```
if ( isset($_POST['name']) ) {
    // work here
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm to check if an specific var was posted. Thks!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, It should be like below:

```
if (isset($_SERVER) && isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  # if method is post, code goes here.
}
```

and if you are sure that your method is POST for sure. and you have  **data post** in `$_POST` you can use code like below:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] != '') {# I think, '' instead of 0
  # if data is posted, code goes here.
}
```

I usually prefer `$_POST`.